# C# - SQLCMD didn't recognised standard input

Tags: c#, batch-file, cmd, stdin, sqlcmd

if you didn't pass any password for SQLCMD it will try to read it from stdin (I can do it manually and it works).

I started cmd process to which i pass the streamWriter with the password as standard input.

Process starts correctly and I can print passed stream, but i got

```
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Login failed for user 'sa'
```

Is there any way to make sqlcmd read stdin?

C# code

```
ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = @"path_to_my_script",
                UseShellExecute = false,
                CreateNoWindow = false,
                RedirectStandardInput = true
            };

            var process = Process.Start( processStartInfo );

            StreamWriter myStreamWriter = process.StandardInput;

            string pass = "123";

            myStreamWriter.WriteLine( pass );

            myStreamWriter.Close();
```

myScript (modified query)

```
SqlCmd -S DESKTOP-UR7LHEE -U sa -Q "SELECT * FROM myDb"
```

Comment: Not sure. Can't you use the '<' command input?

Comment: Why would you do this from C#, why not just connect directly using `SqlConnection`

Comment: @Charlieface In c# im actually only starting the process (batch script that backup my database)

Comment: @MitchWheat for test purposes

Comment: Are you on a Mac? On Mac it doesn't work with stdin but it should on Windows.

Comment: @PaulSinnema no no, Im on Windows, and i didn't catch your first comment, can you explain?

Comment: Still don't get why you are doing it like that. What about making it an SQL Server Agent job and starting the job?

Comment: @MTS You should be able to use > for output and < for input at the end of your command line > = stdout < = stdin for as far as I know. But I could be wrong.

Comment: @MTS What do you expect to read from stdin?

Comment: @PaulSinnema I want to read password, and it works correctly, just SQLCMD didn't "see" it.

Comment: @MTS So it works now or are you still having trouble? B.t.w. I agree that you shouldn't use 'sa'. That account has too many rights and could become a vulnerability.

Comment: @PaulSinnema you don't understand me :d, stream is correctly passed to the script and I can read it, but SQLCMD still does not see it as stdin

Comment: @MTS I think you need this: startInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;

Comment: @MTS: Forget I mentioned that. You already have that.

Comment: @MTS I'm afraid I can't help you.

Comment: @MTS: Maybe this helps?  myStreamWriter.Flush(); before the close()

Comment: @PaulSinnema still nothing, i print the stream in script but sqlcmd didn't see it

Comment: @MTS And this: process.WaitForExit();

Comment: Seriously guys.. Just replicate the `SqlCmd` command using the `ProcessStartInfo` object, you're missing the arguments in the command,.  Can you point me to your C# command that has **-S DESKTOP-UR7LHEE -U sa** ?

Comment: Agreed, we can't answer this without code. I still maintain you're using the wrong tool for the job

Comment: @JeremyThompson SqlCmd is inside a `script.bat`, which argument im missing? It works correctly when i run it manually in cmd: `script.bat < pass`

Comment: @MTS Did you try my last suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following shows how to use [System.Diagnostics.Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process?view=net-6.0) to run a SQL script using [sqlcmd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/scripting/sqlcmd-use-the-utility?view=sql-server-ver15). However, you may want to see if [Server Management Objects (SMO)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/server-management-objects-smo/overview-smo?view=sql-server-ver15) meets your needs.

The following has been tested:

**Add the following using statements**:

- using Microsoft.Win32;
- using System.IO;
- using System.Diagnostics;

First, we'll create a method to query the registry to find the path to sqlcmd.exe:

**Note**: If the directory/folder that sqlcmd.exe exists in is in your PATH environment variable, then the method below is unnecessary - one can use "sqlcmd.exe" instead of the fully-qualified filename.

**GetSqlCmdPath**:

```
private string GetSqlCmdPath()
{
    //get the fully-qualified path for sqlcmd.exe

    string sqlCmdPath = string.Empty;

    using (RegistryKey key = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64))
    {
        using (RegistryKey subkey = key.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server"))
        {
            if (subkey != null)
            {
                string[] subkeyNames = subkey.GetSubKeyNames();

                if (subkeyNames != null)
                {
                    foreach (string name in subkeyNames)
                    {
                        string clientSetupSubkey = Path.Combine(name, "Tools", "ClientSetup");

                        using (RegistryKey subkeyClientSetup = subkey.OpenSubKey(clientSetupSubkey))
                        {
                            if (subkeyClientSetup != null)
                            {
                                string[] valueNames = subkeyClientSetup.GetValueNames();

                                if (valueNames != null)
                                {
                                    foreach (string vName in valueNames)
                                    {
                                        if (vName == "Path" || vName == "ODBCToolsPath")
                                        {
                                            //get value
                                            string valPath = subkeyClientSetup.GetValue(vName)?.ToString();

                                            //check if sqlcmd.exe exists
                                            if (File.Exists(Path.Combine(valPath, "sqlcmd.exe")))
                                            {
                                                sqlCmdPath = Path.Combine(valPath, "sqlcmd.exe");
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }  
    }

    return sqlCmdPath;    
}
```

Next, create a method that uses an instance of Process to execute the script:

**RunProcessSqlCmd**:

```
private void RunProcessSqlCmd(string scriptFilename, string logFilename, string password)
{
    string sqlCmdPath = GetSqlCmdPath();

    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(sqlCmdPath))
        throw new Exception("Error: Fully-qualified path to 'sqlcmd.exe' could not be determined.");

    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo ()
    {
        Arguments = String.Format(@"-S .\SQLExpress -U appAdmin -i {0} -o {1}", scriptFilename, logFilename),
        //Arguments = String.Format(@"-S .\SQLExpress -U appAdmin -i {0}", scriptFilename),
        CreateNoWindow = true,
        FileName = sqlCmdPath,
        RedirectStandardError = true,
        RedirectStandardInput = true,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        UseShellExecute = false,
        WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
    };

    using (Process p = new Process () { StartInfo = startInfo, EnableRaisingEvents = true})
    {
        //subscribe to event and add event handler code
        p.ErrorDataReceived += (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Data))
            {
                //ToDo: add desired code 
                Debug.WriteLine("Error: " + e.Data);
            }
        };

        //subscribe to event and add event handler code
        p.OutputDataReceived += (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Data))
            {
                //ToDo: add desired code
                Debug.WriteLine("Output: " + e.Data);
            }
        };

        //start
        p.Start();

        p.BeginErrorReadLine(); //begin async reading for standard error
        p.BeginOutputReadLine(); //begin async reading for standard output

        using (StreamWriter sw = p.StandardInput)
        {
            //provide values for each input prompt
            //ToDo: add values for each input prompt - changing the for loop as necessary
            //Note: Since we only have 1 prompt, using a loop is unnecessary - a single 'WriteLine' statement would suffice
            for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
            {
                if (i == 0)
                    sw.WriteLine(password); //1st prompt
                else
                    break; //exit
            }
        }

        //waits until the process is finished before continuing
        p.WaitForExit();
    }
}
```

**Note**: The code above writes the output of the script to a log file. If you'd rather write the output to StandardOutput, change the following:

**From**:

```
Arguments = String.Format(@"-S .\SQLExpress -U appAdmin -i {0} -o {1}", scriptFilename, logFilename),
```

**To**:

```
Arguments = String.Format(@"-S .\SQLExpress -U appAdmin -i {0}", scriptFilename),
```

Also, since the `logFilename` parameter will no longer be used, you can remove it.

**Usage**:

```
//create test script
string logFilename = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name + "_ScriptLog.txt");
string scriptFilename = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name + "_Script.sql");
Debug.WriteLine($"scriptFilename: {scriptFilename} logFilename: {logFilename}");

//string scriptText = "use master;" + System.Environment.NewLine;
//scriptText += "SELECT name, database_id from sys.databases;";
string scriptText = "SELECT name, database_id from sys.databases;";
File.WriteAllText(scriptFilename, scriptText);

RunProcessSqlCmd(scriptFilename, logFilename, "myPassword123");
```

**Resources**:

- [System.Diagnostics.Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process?view=net-6.0)
- [Download sqlcmd utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility?view=sql-server-ver15)
- [sqlcmd - Use the utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/scripting/sqlcmd-use-the-utility?view=sql-server-ver15)
- [View list of databases on SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/view-a-list-of-databases-on-an-instance-of-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15)

**Server Management Objects (SMO) Resources**:

- [Server Management Objects (SMO) - Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/server-management-objects-smo/overview-smo?view=sql-server-ver15)
- [Installing Server Management Objects (SMO)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/server-management-objects-smo/installing-smo?view=sql-server-ver15)
- [Programming Specific Tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/server-management-objects-smo/tasks/programming-specific-tasks?view=sql-server-ver15)
- [Backing Up and Restoring Databases and Transaction Logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/server-management-objects-smo/tasks/backing-up-and-restoring-databases-and-transaction-logs?view=sql-server-ver15)
- [Getting Started in SMO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/server-management-objects-smo/getting-started-in-smo?view=sql-server-ver15)
- [Creating SMO Programs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/server-management-objects-smo/create-program/creating-smo-programs?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: this is basically the same code for piping in the password as OP had, why does this one work and OPs not?

Comment: @pm100: Almost, but not quite. The differences are that the OP appears to be trying to call a batch file to execute `sqlcmd` - I execute it directly.  Also, I set `CreateNoWindow = true` and `WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden`. Most importantly, my code works.

Comment: Right.  "Replace your non-working code with this working code" is a fine answer in this case.

Comment: Well @user9938 I don't know what I can say, it just works perfect, thanks for complex explanation

Comment: @MTS: I wouldn't say it's complex, but thorough. You're welcome.