# Trying to Use Process.Start() to automate executing an exe file

Tags: c#

I am trying to Use Process.Start() to automate executing an exe file.

I will first elaborate how to execute the exe file manually:

first, load the exe file by double click it, and after loading, the terminal will show entry info and the last line, the string 'udec>' is the place to type in commands (please ignore the Chinese characters due to my OS).

```
--- module2d plugin DFNModule2D loaded.
--- module2d plugin GeometryModule2D loaded.
--- module2d plugin Convert loaded.


                        U D E C: VERSION 7.00
               赏屯屯屯屯屯屯屯屯屯屯屯屯屯屯屯屯屯屯屯屯屯突
               ?     Universal Distinct Element Code       ?
               掏屯屯屯屯屯屯屯屯屯屯屯屯屯屯屯屯屯屯屯屯屯凸
               ?Copyright (c):Itasca Consulting Group 2017 ?
               ?                                           ?
               韧屯屯屯屯屯屯屯屯屯屯屯屯屯屯屯屯屯屯屯屯屯图
                Licensee:      Itasca Consulting Group, Inc.
                               Minneapolis, Minnesota  USA
                Options:
                               Barton-Bandis
                               Creep
                               CppUdm
                               Flow
                               Thermal


                Memory:          4096 MBytes
                Precision:     Double
udec>
```

then I will type in command call 'D:\Work\202205\20220525\tunnel-for-cmd.txt' to execute it, and the result screenshot is as follows:

```
 udec>call 'D:\Work\202205\20220525\tunnel-for-cmd.txt'

 ................
 ................
 calculation results
 ................
 ................
```

What I am trying is to automate this activity, I use while loop and read from StandardOutput by `int v = p.StandardOutput.Read();`, and `if v == 62` (which means I reached the end of the output, the '**>**' character), I will then write my command line to standard input. and my code is as follows:

```
try
        {
            var psi = new ProcessStartInfo()
            {
                UseShellExecute = false,
                FileName = @"D:\Program Files\ITASCA\UDEC700\Exe64\udecConsole2017.exe",
                //Arguments = @"call 'D:\Work\202205\20220525\tunnel-for-cmd.txt'",
                RedirectStandardInput = true,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                CreateNoWindow = true,
            };
            var p = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(psi);
            // Read until the udec> prompt
            while (true)
            {
                //var line = p.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
                //if (line.StartsWith("udec>"))
                //    break;
                int v = p.StandardOutput.Read();
                Console.Write((char)v);
                if (v == 62)
                {
                    break;
                }
                if (v == -1)
                    break;
            }

            // Write the command
            Console.Write(@"call 'D:\Work\202205\20220525\tunnel-for-cmd.txt'");
            p.StandardInput.WriteLine(@"call 'D:\Work\202205\20220525\tunnel-for-cmd.txt'");
            p.StandardInput.Flush();

            // Read the result
            string content = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

            p.WaitForExit();
            Console.WriteLine(content);
           
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
```

If I run the above code, I will get the starting information as expected (which is exactly the same with the first screenshot). Howerver, my simulation of `call 'D:\Work\202205\20220525\tunnel-for-cmd.txt'` fails. Although `p.StandardInput.WriteLine(@"call 'D:\Work\202205\20220525\tunnel-for-cmd.txt'")` can be executed, when code runs after line 44 (`string content = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();`), the program got hang up and deadlocked, and does not response so that I can only kill this progam.

In order to get the content, I also tried many other solution from stackoverflow, such as using Async method, use OutputDataReceived event and BeginOutputReadLine() method, but all these methods got failed.

I am not sure how to solve it.

Comment: Posting images of technical information like code or terminal outputs, instead of formatted text, is the fastest way I've seen here for a question to be downvoted and then closed or ignored. Even the console output can be copy/pasted into a `<pre>` block.

Comment: `ReadToEnd()` probably blocks because the program never exits. You may need to close the program or maybe wait for another "udec>" prompt and send a "quit" command. It depends on how that particular program works.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp actually I also used while loop trying to get the result (just as I did for printing the starting information), but  the code run `p.StandardOutput.Read() ` at first time and got deadlocked.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Do you know how to close the program?

Comment: I don't know anything about that app, but it looks like "tunnel-for-cmd.txt" is a bunch of commands for it to execute. Can you add a "quit" command as the last action in the script?

Comment: Or, if you are not using the output of the program, sleep for x seconds then use the [`Process.Kill Method`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.kill?view=net-6.0)

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71459143/10024425 (see the code in "RunProcessSqlCmd:")

Comment: @JohnnyMopp  I added `program quit` in txt file but nothing changed. Actually `call 'D:\Work\202205\20220525\tunnel-for-cmd.txt'` will start a long-time cycling computation which will last about 10 seconds during which the terminal will write out information consistantly. I doubt if this makes the output deadlocked but I don't know how to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear if StandardInput is ever exiting. Also `EnableRaisingEvents = true` should be specified. It's not necessary to read the output in order to send input. The code below shows how to provide input using StandardInput. In the code below, the first prompt will be `i = 0`. If a second prompt occurs, this would be specified with `i = 1`.

Try the following:

**Add the following using statements**:

- `using System.IO;`
- `using System.Diagnostics;`

**RunProcess**:

```
private void RunProcess()
{
    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
    {
        CreateNoWindow = true,
        FileName = @"D:\Program Files\ITASCA\UDEC700\Exe64\udecConsole2017.exe",
        RedirectStandardError = true,
        RedirectStandardInput = true,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        UseShellExecute = false,
        WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
    };

    using (Process p = new Process() { StartInfo = startInfo, EnableRaisingEvents = true })
    {
        //subscribe to event and add event handler code
        p.ErrorDataReceived += (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Data))
            {
                //ToDo: add desired code 
                Debug.WriteLine("Error: " + e.Data);
            }
        };

        //subscribe to event and add event handler code
        p.OutputDataReceived += (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Data))
            {
                //ToDo: add desired code
                Debug.WriteLine("Output: " + e.Data);
            }
        };

        //start
        p.Start();

        p.BeginErrorReadLine(); //begin async reading for standard error
        p.BeginOutputReadLine(); //begin async reading for standard output

        using (StreamWriter sw = p.StandardInput)
        {
            //provide values for each input prompt
            //ToDo: add values for each input prompt - changing the for loop as necessary
            //Note: Since we only have 1 prompt, using a loop is unnecessary - a single 'WriteLine' statement would suffice
            for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
            {
                //if there are additional prompts add them below; else if (i = 1)...
                if (i == 0)
                    sw.WriteLine(@"call 'D:\Work\202205\20220525\tunnel-for-cmd.txt'"); //1st prompt
                else
                    break; //exit
            }
        }

        //waits until the process is finished before continuing
        p.WaitForExit();
    }
}
```

**Resources**:

- [Process Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process?view=netframework-4.8)
- [Process.EnableRaisingEvents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.enableraisingevents?view=netframework-4.8)